# KeyChain Export Certificate fails with "You failed to provide the necessary administrator authorisation"

Tags: macos, keychain

I have a `localhost` certificate and a `Imported Private Key` in my Keychain located under the `login` Keychains which I am unable to export.

When I try to export and even if I enter the correct admin password, I get an error dialog
stating:

```
"An error has occurred. Unable to export an item."
"You failed to provide the necessary administrator authorisation."
```

- MacOS version: `11.1 (20C69)`
- Keychain Access version: `11.0 (55281.40.7.0.1)`

My steps I follow is:

1. Select the certificate and select "export localhost"
   (right-click),
2. I select a subfolder under my "Documents" to where
   I want to save the  "Certificates.p12" file.
3. Enter no passwords for protecting the exported Items.
4. I allow and enter the password when asked "Keychain Access wants to make a changes"
5. Again when asked for a password the protect the exported items, I
   leave the passwords blank.

Then the Error Dialog is shown:

```
"An error has occurred. Unable to export an item."
"You failed to provide the necessary administrator authorisation."
```